# Can't fix the date using datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

How can I make `8-12` to be displayed as `12-August`. I tried the following but somewhere I'm going wrong that is why I'm getting an error.

Tried like:

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("8-12", '%d-%b').strftime('%b-%d')

print(dt)
```

Output I'm expecting:

```
12-August
```

Error I'm having:

```
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '8-12' does not match format '%d-%b'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("8-12", '%m-%d').strftime('%d-%B')

print(dt)
# 12-August
```

Comment: @asmitu Sure! Glad to help you. :)